# how to convert datetime from certain timezone to UTC ? django DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I am having trouble dealing with dealing with DateTimeField field.

The question is, lets say i created datetime with timezone like that

```
>>> x = datetime.tzinfo("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")
>>> y = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 29, 12, 0, 13, 204815, x)
```

i want to convert "y" to UTC so that I can save it to DateTimeField

How do I do that ?

Here is rest of my console test

```
>>> a = Attendance.objects.last()
>>> a
<Attendance: wawa>
>>> a.updated_at
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 29, 13, 37, 26, 459259, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> a.updated_at = timezone.now()
>>> a.updated_at
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 11, 8, 49, 5, 381198, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> a.updated_at = timezone.now()
>>> a.updated_at
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 11, 8, 52, 33, 243825, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> x = datetime.tzinfo("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")
>>> y = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 29, 12, 0, 13, 204815, x)
>>> y
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 29, 12, 0, 13, 204815, tzinfo=<datetime.tzinfo object at 0x113ac6600>)
>>> y = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 29, 12, 0, 13, 204815, x)
>>> y = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 29, 12, 0, 13, 204815, x)
>>> a.updated_at = y
>>> a.updated_at
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 29, 12, 0, 13, 204815, tzinfo=<datetime.tzinfo object at 0x113ac6600>)
>>> a.save()
>>> a = Attendance.objects.last()
>>> a.updated_at
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 11, 13, 21, 2, 38046, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Answer (score 1):

i got this to work

```
import datetime
import pytz

time_zone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur')

# get naive date
date = datetime.datetime.strptime("28/07/2018", '%d/%m/%Y').date()
# get naive time
time = datetime.time(12, 30)
# combite to datetime
date_time = datetime.datetime.combine(date, time)
# make time zone aware
date_time = time_zone.localize(date_time)

# convert to UTC
utc_date_time = date_time.astimezone(pytz.utc)
# get time
utc_time = utc_date_time.time()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't.
Django's [DateTimeField](https://kite.com/python/docs/django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField) is stored as Postgresql's `datetimetz` type. The datetimetz type doesn't store any timezone information. It is stored as UTC time and when you do SELECTs it displays it according to timezone defined in DB settings.